# Using clang-tidy to analize embedded GCC project

Tags: c++, llvm, clang-tidy

I'm trying to use clang-tidy to parse my project, compiled by arm-none-eabi-g++.

Unfortunately, clang-tidy is not able to find compiler headers, even when given the include path to them.

My compile_commands.json is

```
  [   
    {
    "directory": "C:/LMA/repo/clang-tidy",
    "arguments": [
      "arm-none-eabi-c++",
      "-IC:/nxp/MCUXpressoIDE_11.2.1_4149/ide/tools/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1",
      "-IC:/nxp/MCUXpressoIDE_11.2.1_4149/ide/tools/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard",
      "test.cpp"
    ],
    "file": "./test.cpp"   } ]
```

And the example test.cpp file is:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>

int test()
{
  int temp;
  return 0;
}
```

Clang-tidy shows error:

```
C:/nxp/MCUXpressoIDE_11.2.1_4149/ide/tools/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1\cstdlib:75:15: error: 'stdlib.h' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
#include_next <stdlib.h>
```

So, it properly finds and includes cstdlib, however it is not able to find stdint.h, which is located in the exactly same folder. What's even more irritaiting, it does not include stdlib.h, even when I add

**-include C:/nxp/MCUXpressoIDE_11.2.1_4149/ide/tools/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1/stdlib.h**
to compiler arguments in order to force preinclude.

Any suggestions how to fix this issue are very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the command line you use to launch clang-tidy?

Comment: Simply using "clang-tidy test.cpp"

Comment: Try `clang-tidy -p=compile_commands.json test.cpp`

Comment: The result is exactly the same

Comment: MLapaj did you solve it? What was the problem?

Comment: Not solved yet, not a clue what the problem may be. Maybe clang-tidy just can't work under GCC.

Comment: it works for me with gcc :-(

Comment: Oh, could you share how you got it to find and use GCC compiler headers?

Comment: any update on this? I cant make clang-tidy use my GCC headers as well

Comment: Not really, as I mentioned in another commend, we ended up using PC-lint as our static code analyzer

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit old, but I was having a similar issue so I figured I'd report an answer here in case anyone else comes across this while searching. It appears **clang** doesn't know where to find the standard library headers when compiling using `arm-none-eabi`. *I succeeded by simply adding them*.

In your case *you're still missing the C headers directory*, so you need to add this:
`C:/nxp/MCUXpressoIDE_11.2.1_4149/ide/tools/arm-none-eabi/include/`

(assuming the directory structure is similar to mine).

So your `compile_commands.json` would be:

```
[ {
  "directory": "C:/LMA/repo/clang-tidy",
  "arguments": [
      "arm-none-eabi-g++",
      "-IC:/nxp/MCUXpressoIDE_11.2.1_4149/ide/tools/arm-none-eabi/include",
      "-IC:/nxp/MCUXpressoIDE_11.2.1_4149/ide/tools/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1",
      "-IC:/nxp/MCUXpressoIDE_11.2.1_4149/ide/tools/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard",
      "test.cpp"
  ],
  "file": "./test.cpp"
} ]
```

You should also have `arm-none-eabi-g++` instead of `arm-none-eabi-c++` I believe.

Comment: Thanks, but we eventually ended up using PC-lint as our static code analyzer and I'm not able to check this solution